# Direct reference from DOM object to my object / data?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
// my object
function myObject(id) {
    this.id = id;
}

var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var myObjects = [];

for(i = 0; i < someCount; i++) {
    var id = someData[i].id; // unique value
    var oobject = new myObject(id);
    myObjects.push(oobject);

    // div element
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = id; // note how div id is same as id property - these two are in "pairs" a.k.a the data from that object is meant for that div
    div.className = 'my-div';
    parent.appendChild(div);
}
```

**What are my options? How to make a direct reference from DOM object to my object?**

This doesn't even have to be a separate object, I just need to store some data that I could access directly / O(1) via DOM element.

- Data is changed dynamically and often which rules out `localStorage` in my opinion
- There's too much data for `data-` attribute and I'm worried that it causes some issues
- Works in all modern browsers (also *stealth mode*) and mobiles - not a big plus for `localStorage`

---

I need to be able to get/set my data when DOM element is clicked without any nasty array iterations or searching for the correct object using only some property's value (like *id* in the example above).

- I looked into adding my own properties/data to DOM object itself
  but all I could find was that this is a very bad idea. These posts were old (between 2008 and 2011), how are things in 2016? There is extremely little information about this. This would be the easiest and I would only need 1 line: `myDiv.addEventListener('click', function(e){ var id = e.currentTarget.myObject.id; }`
- I could also assign DOM object to my own object but as far as I know and I couldn't find any information stating otherwise: there's no way to directly get an object by its property *a.k.a* move up in the object's hierarchy.

Comment: Why not to store reference to DOM element as it is `oobject.element = div;` ?

Comment: @c-smile That's what I originally had.. But then how do I access my object **from** DOM element _(not the other way around)_ directly without any iterations or other O(n) actions?

Comment: Put back reference there too: `oobject.element = div;  div.data = oobject;` DOM element is a JS object as anything else so you can assign properties to it. See: http://javascript.info/tutorial/attributes-and-custom-properties#properties

Comment: @c-smile How about probable issues with DOM object manipulations like I read from older articles like IE problems, cloning that object doesn't include your assigned properties etc _(as I mentioned in my question, these posts were up to 8 years old and I couldn't find any newer information about this, I would appriciate if you knew any sources, Im sure things have changed)_ Also, what happens with browser's memory usage if there's two-way reference? It doubles it for this particular situation, right?

Comment: It used to be a problem in IE6 or so, yes. They were using reference counted DOM element references. That created problems with reference cycles. In modern browsers, when you remove DOM element with custom property, it will be freed by GC and so all it properties will go away. And check #3 here:https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/25-techniques-javascript-performance-optimization-steven-de-salas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this in O(1) and without altering DOM nodes is to use an object literal as a Map (hash) linking the node to an object.

You are already setting an `id` attribute on your DOM elements, so you can use each node's id as the key to connect to the appropriate `myObject`:

```
var map = {}; // create the map. map[domNodeID] = appropriate myObject

for(i = 0; i < someCount; i++) {
    var id = someData[i].id;
    var oobject = new myObject(id);

    // div element
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = id;
    div.className = 'my-div';
    parent.appendChild(div);

    // link node and object through the map
    map[id] = oobject;
}
```

Then you can just reference the object using the map:

```
myDiv.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var oobject = map[this.id]; // O(1) lookup
    // use your object
}
```

There is also a built-in object for this purpose called [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which might prove better than using an object literal but it depends on you needed browser support. `Map` does allow using objects as keys as well as strings so you can technically link a node to an object directly, without the need for an id:

```
map.set(node, oobject)
```

Additionally, instead of using direct access like `map[key] = value`, perhaps you can add methods to your custom map that use the same names as `Map` methods, such as `map.set(key, value)` to ensure an easy switch to a `Map` later on.

Comment: Thank you for great answer. All this seems very useful and exciting, I haven't used mapping yet in my coding - lots of research and studying to do now. Cheers!

Comment: @Solo no problem mate, glad to help :)